# ACPI Errors when installing Ubuntu 16.04 on ASUS MAXIMUS X Hero motherboard

Tags: software-installation, asus, acpi, compatibility

I have just purchased a brand new Workstation coming with an Asus ROG MAXIMUS X HERO motherboard (S/N: HAMCKC001229).

Here is some other technical information:

- OS Name   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro (Version   10.0.16299 Build 16299)
- System Type   x64-based PC
- Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70GHz, 3696 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 1003, 21/12/2017
- SMBIOS Version 3.0
- Embedded Controller Version   255.255
- BIOS Mode UEFI
- RAM: 32Gb
- Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Ti

Both C: and G: are WD PCIe SSD 256Gb card.

On C: is installed Windows 10 Pro (properly working). On G: I wanted to install Ubuntu 16.04 (desktop.amd64) LTE (or superior) and have a dual boot. After having prepared an ISO CD-ROM and changed the UEFI/BIOS setting to enable the booting from CD-ROM I could see the GRUB window. Unfortunately though, after selecting "Try Ubuntu Without Installing" I received a black screen with a series of scary ACPI errors (like "AE_NOT_FOUND" or "Namespace lookup failure" or "Method parse/execution failed")! Those errors change all the time in number, but the messages seem to be similar or actually always the same.

[image: Attached is a link to a picture of them]

I have the same problem with a USB drive with the same ISO image. There's no way to get out of such black screen unless I reboot the system. The same thing trying the direct Installing option.

Following one of the suggestions from the Asus Custumer Service I changed the following settings in BIOS/UEFI:

<sub>BIOS > BOOT > FAST BOOT > DISABLED

BIOS > BOOT > CSM > LAUNCH CSM > ENABLED

BIOS > BOOT > SECURE BOOT > OS TYPE > OTHER OS</sub>

without any result.

The Customer Service told me that Asus Rog MAXIMUS X Hero Motherboard doesn't support Linux. Another Asus technician suggested me to download the Ubuntu 17.04 instead because according to him this last one is UEFI compatible. Is this the solution?

Comment: 16.10 is not LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same error. In fact I let the error message run and it kept scrolling continually, with the first number of the error increasing sequentially. It got to number 268 when I decided to reboot, because the way in which this error list was scrolling down the screen I could have waited for hours before it ended.

This is among the first errors of the exceptionally very long sequence:

```
[   0.196051] ACPI Error: [_SB_PCI0_RP05.PSXK] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dswload2-191)
[   0.196057] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20160930/psobject-227)
[   0.196059] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed[\SB.PC10.RP04.PXSX] (nODE FFFF99A45DC40320), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/Psparse-543)
[   3.997845] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: SCHED_ERROR 09 []
etc. etc.
[ 268.902931] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: SCHED_ERROR 09 []
```

So this error began at `0.xxxxxx` (I don't recall what the very first 6 [x] numbers were) but I decided to stop it at line 268 which took a good 5 minutes to reach that far down the list of errors. The system gave a few "OK" here and there at the end of some lines, meaning that what ever devices this was searching for, some things checked out OK.

Another 2 errors that began with # 3 and # 4 respectively at the beginning mentioned 2 devices by `devid 8086:a294 Error status/mask=00000001/00002000` followed on the next line by another related `PCIe bus devid 8086:a296` with the same error status. These are PCIe buses number 5 and 6 on my motherboard (if I recall correctly) in Device Manager of Windows 10.

The only way I was finally able to install Ubuntu 17.04 from USB bootable intallation media was to go into the BIOS and with the installation USB stick plugged in the USB port, there is an option to change the type of emulation that the USB media uses: Auto/Floppy disk/Forced floppy disk/HDD/CD ROM. I chose HDD emulation saved the new BIOS setting, then pressed <kbd>F8</kbd> during boot up, so I could select the USB stick to boot in UEFI mode. I was finally able to install Ubuntu 17.04.

I tried numerous different USB sticks, I tried `unetbootin` and `rufus` and the errors were always reproduced. The only thing that would boot any of these USB sticks was with Windows 10 installation media written to the drives.

Up to that point I thought it might either be a motherboard problem or a BIOS problem. I recently updated the BIOS, so I thought it might be a bad flush.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 16.10 support UEFI without problem, but sometimes making a UEFI bootable USB Drive can be a little tricky, which software have you used to make the USB Bootable drive? I can suggest you to use Rufus, if you have troubles using it follow [this](https://www.vanstechelman.eu/content/creating-an-uefi-bootable-linux-usb-stick) guide.

When you're booting from USB make shure that you're booting in UEFI mode and NOT Legacy mode, i think you can specify to boot in UEFI mode from the booting menu (I've an ASUS Motherboard too, to access to the boot menu i press F8).

If also doing this you're unable to boot the live install try redownloading Ubuntu ISO, or try another version of Ubuntu or another distro to make shure that the problem isn't Ubuntu 16.10

Comment: I've actually used Rufus following step by step the procedure described here: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3.

However, I might have chosen the wrong partition scheme from the drop down menu. I should select GPT partition scheme for UEFI instead.

I'm going to try again and post here the results ...

Thank you for your answer!